# Applying function to a group of objects by same class name but function independently of each other onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to hover over a single svg polygon and have that polygon disappear(opacity 0) revealing something underneath with java script or j query. My problem is I don't know how to separate the ith polygon from the others to only have that polygon disappear. Keep in mind there are many polygons so I don't want to make a new function for each one. Eventually I want to apply the same concept to the other objects (images). The layout looks like honeycomb that will be transparent when you hover over the specific polygon.

I think it has something to do with the i in "svgs[i].style.opacity = '0';" but I just don't know how to fix it and am not sure how to call the ith polygon in the array. Thanks!

```
#tester {
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #7e1d1d;
}

#tester img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#tester .wrap svg {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.cls0 {
    display: inline-block;
    fill: #465761;
    stroke: #666;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-width: 4px;
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ghost() {
      var svgs = document.getElementsByClassName("cls0");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
        svgs[i].style.opacity = '0';

      }
    }
    function normal() {
      var svgs = document.getElementsByClassName("cls0");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
        svgs[i].style.opacity = "1";

      }
    }


  </script>

  <div id="tester">    
    <div class="wrap">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1216.21 504.62">    
        <title>Tester Polygon</title>
        <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
          <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">

            <polygon class="cls0" onmouseover="ghost()" onmouseout="normal()"
              points="89 52.31 89 152.31 175.6 202.31 262.2 152.31 262.2 52.31 175.6 2.31 89 52.31" />

            <image class="testimg" width="225" height="225" transform="translate(138.6 65.31) scale(0.33 0.33)"xlink:href="img\1x\asset6.png" />


            <image class="star" width="225" height="225" transform="translate(138.6 65.31) scale(0.33 0.33)"xlink:href="img\1x\Asset24.png" />





            <polygon class="cls0" onmouseover="ghost()" onmouseout="normal()" points="262 52.31 262 152.31 348.6 202.31 435.2 152.31 435.2 52.31 348.6 2.31 262 52.31" />

            <image class="testimg"  width="225" height="225"transform="translate(311.6 64.31) scale(0.33 0.33)" xlink:href="img\1x\Asset7.png" />


            <image class="star" width="225" height="225" transform="translate(311.6 64.31) scale(0.33 0.33)" xlink:href="img\1x\Asset24.png" />



<polygon class="cls0" points="435 52.31 435 152.31 521.6 202.31 608.21 152.31 608.21 52.31 521.6 2.31 435 52.31" />

            <image class="testimg" width="225" height="225" transform="translate(484.6 65.31) scale(0.33 0.33)"xlink:href="img\1x\Asset8.png" />

            <image class="star" width="225" height="225" transform="translate(484.6 65.31) scale(0.33 0.33)"xlink:href="img\1x\Asset24.png" />

   </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite those functions, assuming that the tag is passed to them:

```
function ghost(that) {
    that.style.opacity = '0';
}
function normal(that) {
    that.style.opacity = '1';
}
```

and make sure you properly pass the value:

```
<polygon class="cls0" onmouseover="ghost(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)"
              points="89 52.31 89 152.31 175.6 202.31 262.2 152.31 262.2 52.31 175.6 2.31 89 52.31" />
```